# 2011 Mazda 6, alarm sounding from little black box that sits under the dashboard

Tags: mazda-6

I own a 2011 Mazda 6, today an alarm sound started going off under the dashboard, so I got down and checked and it seems to be coming from the little black box that sits right above the brake and gas pedal. I've tried Googling this and found nothing. Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Image of where it's coming from:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google found me what looks like the part number on that pic (L5A9-18-9E1A):
https://www.realmazdaparts.com/oem-parts/mazda-trans-controller-l5a9189e1d

Listing's a bit different for that one, but short version, 9E1D is the updated version of 9E1A/B/C Transmission Controller.

Local Mazda dealer should know more....